# What is wrong with the following code dealing with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Am I handling the pointer the wrong way? I want to update the value of a variable by passing it's address to the function.

```
void func(int *p){
        int x = 3;
        p = &x;
}

int main(){
        int y = 0;
        func(&y);
        printf("\n Value = %d",y);
}
```

I get the following output:

> Value = 0 
>   Exited: ExitFailure 11

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must dereference the pointer to replace the value on which the pointer points.

See:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int *p){
        int x = 3;
        *p = x;
}

int main(){
    int y = 0;
    func(&y);
    printf("\n Value = %d",y);
    return 0;
}
```

To remove the exit failure add the return 0; statement into the main function.

See running example:
http://ideone.com/rO8Gua

Answer (score 7):

```
void func(int *p){
    *p = 3;
}
```

You were setting `p` to the address of a local variable `x`. First, setting the value of `p` doesn't change the value of `y` (the function just receives a copy of the address of `y`, and even if you change that, you are not going to change `y`).

Second, x is a local variable, so you cannot use it's content after the function `func` is terminated.

Third, you cannot change the address of `y` in this way because it is a local variable. You would need to declare it as a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to content of memory referred to by p by using *p. So, `p =&x;` will change p not the content of memory referred to by p. You should have used, `*p = x`

Answer (score 4):

You mean you want to set the value at `p` to `x`? That's

```
*p = x;
```

What you've actually got, `p = &x`, means change the local copy of the pointer to point to your local variable instead.